# Firebase Cloud Functions - Function triggered when user logged in

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

On this [doc page](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/auth-events), `Firebase` gives two callback functions triggered when an auth operation happens: `onCreate()` and `onDelete()`. My question is that is there any callback that is triggered when each time a user is logged in to my app? Like `onSignedIn()` or sth like that...